# Problem with encryption/Decryption code written in Jmeter

Tags: java, encryption, jmeter

I have written a code in beanshell for encryption and decryption in Jmeter but somehow its not working. I am getting error :  ``` In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException; import java.security.In . . . '' Encountered "}" ``` at line 19, column 82.
I have added the crypto jar in test plan but issue persists.

Attached is the code.

Working :

1. I am generating a random string(R1) and encryption it with a public key using RSA algo.
2. Using the key R1, I need to encrypt the request body using AES algo, CBC mode, PKCS7Padding.

```
        package com.sample.feedbackrating;
        import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
        import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
        import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
        import java.security.SecureRandom;
        import java.util.Base64;
        import java.util.UUID;
        import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
        import javax.crypto.Cipher;
        import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
        import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
        import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
        import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    public class Crypto {
    

        public static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }

        public static String encrypt(String algorithm, String input, String secretKey, IvParameterSpec iv) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException

    {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new 
    SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "AES"), iv);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    }
    
    public static String decrypt(String algorithm, String cipherText, String secretKey, IvParameterSpec iv) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException

    {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "AES"), iv);
    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
    return new String(plainText);
}

        public static String generateSecretKey() {
            return UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Encountered "}"` is a syntax error so double check your Beanshell script for eventual missing semicolons or closing brackets or whatever. You can use online lint tool like [this one](https://tio.run/#beanshell) to see where exactly the problem is

In general I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

So it's either a copy-paste issue or a Beanshell-related problem, be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead), especially for "heavy" tasks like cryptographic operations.

Comment: Thanks for your help !! Code is working fine now. 
Could you please help me with another query ? 

- In encrypt method, we are calling Crypto.generateIv directly.

My requirement is to execute the Crypto.generateIv before encrypt method and save the value of generateSecretkey in a variable and pass it as a parameter in Method- encrypt.

Comment: This worked :

def Secretkey = Crypto.generateSecretKey();
log.info("SecretKey:" + Secretkey)